# How can I find the INSTANCE_ID from a provisioned machine?

Tags: openstack

How can I find the [Instance ID](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/instancedata.html#v1-instance-id) referred to by Cloud-Init as provided by OpenStack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run,

```
cloud-init query instance_id
```

Or, you can find the `INSTANCE_ID`, by looking in this file,

```
/var/lib/cloud/data/instance-id
```

Or, this one

```
/run/cloud-init/.instance-id
```