# Does cloud-init store the copy of the init it ran first?

Tags: terraform, configuration, cloud-init

I'm sending my cloud-init file to Terraform via `user_data`. Is this stored anywhere on the machine that runs it? I know it may get merged with other stuff before it's run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be stored under

```
/var/lib/cloud/instances
```

Under your [instance id](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/15483/18965).

```
cd /var/lib/cloud/instances/$(cloud-init query instance_id)
```

For me I found the information I wanted in `user-data.txt`.

```
sudo cat "/var/lib/cloud/instances/$(cloud-init query instance_id)/user-data.txt"
```